# How do I get suspend working on my Dell Precision 5530, running Ubuntu 18.10 and nVidia proprietary driver 390?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, suspend

When I suspend my Laptop it suspends fine (takes a bit until the fans turn off), but when I wake it there's only a static underscore at the top left and i have to hold the power button to restart the laptop.
I am running the `4.15.0-1024-oem` kernel on Ubuntu 18.10 with the proprietary nVidia drivers 390 installed via the Software & Updates GUI, on an nVidia Quadro P2000. I have tried the 410 drivers with the 4.19.1 kernel but that yields the same result. The only time it worked properly was on kernel 4.19.1 before I installed the 410 drivers, and the 390 were incompatible with the kernel and therefore not loaded.

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

yields the following

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro P2000/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.87
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.87
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 390.87
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I got it working with the newest nvidia drivers (`460.32.03` at the time of writing). I am now using the nvidia on-demand profile in `nvidia-settings` and run things where I need a gpu with `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia` prepended to the command or with the context-menu option.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device since yesterday but with the P1000 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I've run into the same problem.

The only working solution for me was using the free Nouveau driver.

Comment: Yeah, I just decided to live with the problem, since without the nvidia driver the laptop just uses the intel graphics in firefox and maxes out individual cores, and firefox also uses the intel graphics for hardware acceleration without the nvidia drivers.

Comment: I don't really experience any major problems with the Intel GPU. It would be nice to have the P1000 for gaming but at least it doesn't use tons of power.

Comment: I don't have the exact same specs as your model. However I've got mine finally working with the following setup.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- No changes to grub
- Installed all the `linux-generic-hwe` packages
- installed the nvidia-390 driver

After this everything (suspend ect.) seems to be working in Gnome Wayland and ARMA 3 gives me decent frame rates. I've only tried it today and therefore haven't really invested much time into Gnome Xorg or i3wm. However it seems to crash everytime I select one of those environments.

Comment: Isn't nvidia disabled in Wayland and the default driver is used?

Comment: Is that still the case? I must admint I'm really bad with this GPU stuff. I never really got a dual graphics setup to work reliably on any of my notebooks. Do you know how to check which card it's using?

Comment: I think you can check in the nvidia xserver settings, or just type `nvidia-smi` into the terminal

Comment: Thanks I'll try the command. The Nvidia xserver settings however don't work under wayland.

Comment: Tried the command but it doesn't work. I managed to boot into i3wm with Xorg and there the command doesn't work as well but the nvidia driver is installed.