# nvidia driver 390 not working after kernel update to 5.11

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, updates

I've seen a related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090542/how-do-i-get-suspend-working-on-my-dell-precision-5530-running-ubuntu-18-10-and), but it seems I'm not reputable enough to post there.

As so many times in the past, the most recent kernel appears incompatible with the nvidia driver (for me 390). What happens is that the monitor configuration is messed up (I can see only one of my two monitors and with wrong size).

Currently the only working kernel is 5.8.0.59. None of the 5.11... works properly.

I've messed up my computer in the past moving from nvidia to nouveau. Any alternative solution?

By the way, why is it so important to push the new kernels when there is this persistent problem with nvidia drivers? The related post mentioned above is from February, so the current issue is not super new.

Cheers

Gianni

Comment: You should be aware 5.11 is not the latest kernel there is a 5.12

Comment: Users using Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices; as always the most *stable* is the GA kernel (applies with all LTS releases; this is not new), which started at 5.4 with 20.04 and remains at 5.4 for the entire life of Ubuntu 20.04.  You could have chosen to use that kernel stack choice. There is also the HWE or *hardware enablement* kernel stack choice, which upgrades from GA to the 20.10 stack (ie 5.8), then 21.04 (ie. 5.11), then 21.10 (unknown currently), before finally reaching the GA stack of 22.04 (unknown currently).  If you want maximum stability - use the GA kernel

Comment: ps:   you can have both stacks installed too (I do on a number of my boxes; you can select which you use at boot), the only effect is both will get upgraded thus more disk space & bandwidth used for upgrades; but it's not significant in my opinion.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   (*installation media will decide which is the default; eg. Ubuntu Server defaults to GA, *flavor* media for 20.04 & 20.04.1 defaults to GA, Ubuntu Desktop & *flavor* media 20.04.2 & higher default to HWE, but it can be changed anytime)

Comment: Thanks David, noted.

Comment: Thanks guiverc, I didn't know of those options. I'll look them up!

Answer (score 0):

right after posting my previous message and rebooting, the graphical interface broke down completely (only console log in). I ran apt update and apt upgrade and a new version of nvidia-driver-390 for kernel 5.11 was installed. What are the chances!?!?!? (note that is did update/upgrade already once in graphic mode just minutes before)

Anyway, problem solved for now.
Cheers
Gianni